# How can we derive the definition of a subset $\forall x (x\in A \implies x \in B))$ form the ZFC Set Theory Axioms

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Hi I feel like this is a trivial question (I apologize before hand if it is) I am currently self studying set theory and the notion of a subset $\forall x (x\in A \implies x \in B))$ in ZFC Set Theory is both in the Extensionality Axiom and the Power Set Axiom:

\[ \forall A \forall B \left[ \forall x(x\in A \iff x\in B) \implies A=B \right] \]
and
\[ \forall a \exists B \forall x (x\in B \iff \forall c (c\in x \implies c \in a))\]

But it itself is not a Axiom. Can the definition of a subset be derived from the axioms of ZFC for example (Please excuse any error in my logic i welcome any correction):

\[ \forall A \forall B \exists C \forall x (x\in C \iff x\in A \land A\cup B =B)\]
Using the axiom of specification here $C$ would be the subset of the sets $A$ and $B$ and the union of them then must be $B$ if $A$ is a subset there of or

\[ \forall A \forall B \exists C \forall x (x\in C \iff x\in A \land A\cap B =A)\]

Again using the axiom of specification here $C$ would be the subset of the sets $A$ and $B$ but now we use there intersection if we assume we already derived it from the axiom of specification. In both these $C$ should also exist because $C\in \wp B$ and thus the power set axiom.

Is there a simpler derivation or understanding of a subset because as I understand it we only work with the axioms of ZFC and can from there derive any necessary sets we need like the subset or am I just misunderstanding something?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do.  Definitions don't need to be (and can't be) "derived"; a definition is just assigning a meaning to a symbol or word that previously had no meaning.

Comment: I understand @EricWofsey could the subset then be some sort of theorem or result like the intersection is which can be derived from the Axiom of Separation?

Comment: "Subset" is just an abbreviation. "$B\subseteq A$" is a short way of saying "$\forall x(x\in B\to x\in A)$". That is all it is. It's not a "theorem". It's not a "result".

Comment: @Martin You are confusing definition with existence. Intersection is a definition, while you need to prove that for every two sets their intersection is also a set.

Comment: @ReijoJaakkola Oh! Okay do we then not think of a subset as a set or rather can we show that a subset of a set is a set or is that already true?

Comment: By definition, a subset of a set $A$ is a set $B$ such that $\forall x(x\in B\to x\in A)$. So subsets are sets **by definition**. Being a subset of $A$ is not a construction, it is a description of a property that a set may or may not have (relative to $A$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I get that Is the subset I am talking about then just a given?

Comment: Ohh @ArturoMagidin am I confusing the notation then Does it read:
Given 2 sets $A$ and $B$ for every element in $A$ those elements are in $B$
Or
Given a set $A$ its subset is the set $B$ such that for every element in $B$ those elements are in $A$?

Comment: Those are mangled sentences; your third displayed formula defines $C$ as empty if $B\not\subseteq A$ and as $A$ if $B\subseteq A$. Your fourth displayed formula defines $C$ as empty if $A\not\subseteq B$ and as $A$ if $A\subseteq B$. Both are trivially definable using separation; the first with $\phi(x)=x\in A\wedge B\in P(A)$. The second with $\psi(x)=x\in A\wedge A\in P(B)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That makes sense would both then describe a type of subset?

Comment: "Type of subset" is nonsense. Subset is not a property that a set has or doesn't have. it's a property that a set has *in relation to some other set*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ahh Okay so a subset is not something derived from the axioms its a property it has - like you said - in relation to another set?

Answer (score 0):

The axiom schema of [separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) is what ensures the existence of many subsets. It asserts that for any set $A$ and any logical formula $\varphi$, there is a set consisting of precisely the elements of $A$ that satisfy $\varphi$. Symbolically: $$\exists C,\forall x(x\in C\iff x\in A\land\varphi(x)).$$ The axiom of extensionality ensures that this $C$ is unique (for a given $A$ and $\varphi$), so we can unambiguously define the "set-builder notation" expression $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}$ to refer to it.

Intersections are a case of this. When we define $A\cap B$ to mean $\{x\in A:x\in B\}$, we're indirectly relying on separation with $\varphi(x)=(x\in B)$ to get the theorem $\forall A \forall B \exists C(x\in C \iff x\in A\land x\in B)$.

We don't need an existence theorem to define the notion of subsets in general, because "subset" is not an "operation that produces a set" like separation and intersection (and powerset, union, etc.) are. The expression $A\subseteq B$ is short for $\forall x(x\in A\implies x\in B)$, which is a *sentence* rather than a *term* referring to an object. We don't refer to "the subset of $A$" (singular) because subsets aren't unique in general.

Comment: Ohh this makes the idea a lot simpler and more clear. Thank you for clarifying I appreciate it!